# Creating a Mockup of Lightning Communities

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder

I am already aware that salesforce uses tools like Sketch to create mockups for lightning components by using SLDS. I recently given a project to create a mockup of salesforce communities. Are there any tools to use regarding this requirement?

Comment: I like Avonni Creator (not affiliated with that product) for standard Lightning component design, and it has a Communities mode.